# Determine all points $a$ where piecewise function is continuous and differentiable

Tags: derivatives, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I need to check for which points $a \in \mathbb{R}$ the following function is $(1)$ continuous and $(2)$ differentiable at $x=a$.

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
-2x + 1, & \text{for } x \lt -1 \\
x^2, & \text{for} -1 \le x \le 1 \\
x^3, & \text{for }  x \gt 1
\end{cases}$

So for checking for which $a$ it is continuous, is it sufficient to check the three continuity-conditions for the values $x = -1, 1$? These seem to be the most interesting here.

For checking the differentiability, I did evaluate $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}$ for all 3 parts of the function, and ended up with $-2$, $2a$ and $3a^2$ respectively for the first, second and third term. Are these the points a for which the function is differentiable?

I am familiar how to check for a normal function, but not so sure about this piecewise function.

Edit:

So checking $\lim\limits_{x \to -1^{-}}{-2x+1} = 3$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to -1^{+}}{x^2} = 1$ shows that the function is not continuous at $x=-1$. Doing the same for $1^+$ and $1^{-}$ yields both 1, so it is continuous at $x=1$. Since the individual sub-functions are continuous on their respective intervals, it can be concluded that it is everywhere continuous except at $x=-1$.

Comment: These are elementary functions, so they are continuous and differentiable on their intervals. All you need to do is to check the cases for $x=-1,1$. In particular, the function may not be differentiable on $x=-1,1$, since the two one-sided derivatives may not equal.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. Since it is not continuous at -1, it is also not differentiable there. But everywhere else it is continuous, so it remains to check if it is differentiable.

Comment: @Warhost you've made a good observation that continuity is necessary for differentiability. Something which can happen is that the left and right limits of the derivative can be equal, but the function can still fail to be differentiable at a point if it's not continuous there. For example, a function which is constant for $x<0$ and constant for $x \geq 0$ with different constants. Both derivatives are $0$, but at $0$ the derivative is not defined.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Yes that makes sense. However I am still unsure how to check for which points it is differentiable. Which ones do need to be checked?

Comment: Well, if the function is continuous at $1$, just take the derivatives of each piece, and look at the limit as they go to $1$. In other words, you are asking if $x^2$ and $x^3$ have the same derivative at $1$.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Oh so simply taking the derivative would mean that it is 2 and 3 respectively, so they do not have the same derivative at $1$, so not differentiable at $1$?. I am just confused when to use the limit definition of differentiability and when it sufficies to simply take the derivative.